# Selector in UIBarButtonItem not calling

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a selector on my UIBarButton referencing a function to segue to another view controller but the function never gets called when clicked on. Through testing breakpoints I can see the function, segueToCartViewController, never gets called.
Thanks in advance!

UIBarButtonItem init

```
private let reuseIdentifier = "ItemCell"
private let SegueCartIdentifier = "CatalogToCart"

final class CatalogViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    //MARK: -properties

    var brand: Brand!
    var cart: [Item]!

    fileprivate let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 3
    fileprivate let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 20, bottom: 30, right: 20)
    private var cartItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Cart"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(segueToCartViewController(_:)))

    var selectedItemIndexPath: IndexPath?{
        didSet{
            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
            if let selectedItemIndexPath = selectedItemIndexPath{
                indexPaths.append(selectedItemIndexPath)
            }
            if let oldValue = oldValue{
                indexPaths.append(oldValue)
            }

            collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
            }) { completed in
                if let selectedItemIndexPath = self.selectedItemIndexPath{
                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: selectedItemIndexPath, at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)
        let flex = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        self.navigationController?.toolbar.items = [flex,cartItem,flex]
    }
}
```

call for segue

```
//MARK: CartNavigation
extension CatalogViewController: CartDelegate{

    func segueToCartViewController(_ sender: AnyObject){
        super.performSegue(withIdentifier: SegueCartIdentifier, sender: sender)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard let destination = segue.destination as? UINavigationController else{
            return
        }

        cartVC.delegate = self
    }

    func closeModallyPresentedViewController() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in text and not screenshots

Comment: Please post your code in text and not screenshots!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The target of your UIBarButtonItem is nil because `self` is nil during it's initialization.

You can initialize it like this instead

```
final class CatalogViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    lazy final private var cartItem: UIBarButtonItem = { [unowned self] in
        return UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: <#T##String#>), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(segueToCartViewController(_:)))
    }()

    override function viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //blah blah, the rest of your code
    }
}
```

[See here](https://medium.com/the-traveled-ios-developers-guide/swift-initialization-with-closures-5ea177f65a5) for a good explanation about the value of `self` during initialization of properties.

Comment: Now that I did that that the item is not visible. Any ideas? @Allen Humphreys

Comment: If I put the code in viewDidAppear function, pressing where the button should be works

Comment: The UIBarButtonItem is not visible

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, is it because you used `nil` as your image?

Comment: Oh my bad, sorry for wasting your time. Thank you so much

Comment: Just want to make sure... you got it working, right?

Comment: Yes. Thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome, accepting and upvoting are thanks enough :-)

Comment: The most important thing is to use `lazy` keyword